# python program with decimal library should have accuracy of 50 but instead is much smaller

Tags: python, decimal, python-multithreading, pi

I am using the decimal library in python to increase the accuracy of a program estimating pi to 50 digits. I am currently learning about threading so I have a function that doesn't use threads and one that does. The one without threads works fine, and estimates to 50 digits, however the other function only estimates to around 25 and I have no idea why. Here is the output-3.1415926535897932384466434024794907242010093993346
1.510117769241333
3.141592653589793238478643384
1.4592773914337158

the first line and 3rd are both estimations of pi, with the 2nd and 4th being the time it took to achieve that. The first pi estimation is from the no threads function and is far more accurate than the other. How can I get the other function to be just as accurate?

here is the code

```
from decimal import *
import time
from threading import *
getcontext().prec = 50
def nothreads(t):
    p = 3
    x = 2
    while x < 5000000:
        p += (Decimal(4) /Decimal(x * (x + 1) * (x + 2)) - Decimal(4)/Decimal((x+2)*(x+3)*(x+4)))
        x += 4
    print(p)
    return(time.time() - t)

tot = 3
lock = Lock()

def div1(x):
    global tot
    mysum = 0
    while x < 5000000:
        mysum += (Decimal(4) /Decimal(x * (x + 1) * (x + 2)))
        x += 4
    lock.acquire()
    tot += mysum
    lock.release()
def div2(x):
    global tot
    mysum = 0
    while x < 5000000:
        mysum += (Decimal(4) /Decimal(x * (x + 1) * (x + 2)))
        x += 4
    lock.acquire()
    tot -= mysum
    lock.release()

def threads(t):
    t1 = Thread(target=div1, args=(2,))
    t2 = Thread(target=div2, args=(4,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    global tot
    print(tot)
    return(time.time() - t)

print(nothreads(time.time()))
print(threads(time.time()))
```

Comment: Your `div2` decimal stuff doesn't match what you do without the thread (the formula of the subtrahend), also threads will be slower and I don't see any use for that lock here, it doesn't really achieve anything.

Comment: well the div2 stuff should be about half of what I do in div1, it's the addition portion

Comment: [The doc for contexts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#context-objects) clearly states: "Each thread has its own current context which is accessed or changed using the getcontext() and setcontext() functions:". Just set the precision in each of `div1` and `div2` and you're good.